# SpannableString doesn't work - displays unchanged data

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

does anyone have an idea why the following code does not change the data? The "expired" string is added, but neither the font color nor the size is changed.

```
        Spannable expired = new SpannableString(" expired");
        expired.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, expired.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        expired.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.5f), 0, expired.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        nameTextView.setText(goalsName + expired);
```

xml:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_list_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:text="Cel 1" />
```

Comment: You have to take full string then change(manipulate) the string on basis of index and set the full spannable to string instead of concatenating two different one.

Comment: By concatenating your Spannable to a String you are converting it to another String, removing the styling information.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution:

```
String s = name + " expired";
SpannableString  expired = new SpannableString(s);
expired.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), name.length(), expired.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
expired.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.7f), name.length(), expired.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
nameTextView.setText(expired);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `Spannable`, You should be using `SpannableString` instead. Change your code as below.

```
String s = "oldString"+" expired";
SpannableString expired=  new SpannableString(s);
expired.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 10, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
expired.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.5f), 10, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
nameTextView.setText(expired);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I wonder if I have a set value somewhere that covers the changes made here, but I do not see anything.

Comment: try clean and build your project, I have checked and this works.

Comment: I can share my screen if you want

Comment: The wrong value was returned in your code. We should set setText (expired). Then it works

Comment: there was an edit earlier by someone, didn't notice it was changed. I have changed it.